# SQL Azure query termination

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I remember reading somewhere that SQL Azure is going to terminate long-running queries. Is there a time limit on how long a query can run against a database before it is terminated? Where I work, I run complex queries against large tables that take about 5 minutes each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure will terminate web-requests that are IDLE for more than 1 minute and that are made over the load-balancer (meaning from the outside to its web servers).

Azure will also throttle your slow-running queries, but only if they take resources away from the other tenants in the SQL server instance that your database is in.  I do not believe there are any published statistics as to precise metrics when such throttling will occur.

Answer (score 9):

SQL Azure Connection Limit is written by MSDN Library and technet wiki.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx#cc
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-connection-management.aspx

For example,

> SQL Azure kills all transactions after they run for 24 hours. If you
>   lose a connection due to this reason, you will receive error code
>   40549.

and

> Large transactions, transactions executed in large batches, or large
>   sorts might consume a significant tempdb space. When a session uses
>   more than 5 GB of tempdb space (= 655,360 pages), the session is
>   terminated.